# Use mitmproxy to translate a form key/value to a body post

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am trying to use mitmproxy to adapt requests from a client (monitoring agent) which I can't change.

The client cannot POST data, e.g. JSON or SOAP XML data to the request. It can only post form name/value pairs (or header name/values).

I'm trying to work around this limitation by:

- getting the client to post a form pair: "phony_key="
- using mitmproxy to remove the key and just post the data

Running the proxy with a replace expression to just strip the "phony_key=" looked good initially

```
mitmproxy --replace /~bq/phony_param=/
```

... and produced a good result when I invoked a request from curl, something like

```
curl -d phony_param='<SOAP-ENV:Envelope></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> https://host:port/path
```

But when invoked from the real client, the request was rejected by the server.

I think it is because the data payload when sent from the real client is urlencoded. Inspecting the request in mitmproxy using the hex option shows that.

```
0000000000 25 33 43 53 4f 41 50 2d 45 4e 56 25 33 41 45 6e   %3CSOAP-ENV%3AEn
0000000010 76 65 6c 6f 70 65 2b 78 6d 6c 6e 73 25 33 41 53   velope+xmlns%3AS
0000000020 4f 41 50 2d 45 4e 56 3d 25 32 32 68 74 74 70 25   OAP-ENV=%22http%
```

Whereas the request made by curl invocation shows the un-encoded XML in the hex view.

Since then, I've tried to make an inline script to do the job

```
def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.method == "POST":
        form = flow.request.get_form_urlencoded()
        real_post = form.get("phony_param")[0]
        form.__delitem__("phony_param")
        print real_post
        flow.request.content = real_post
        flow.request.set_form_urlencoded(form)
```

Above I'm trying to remove the form name/value, add the value to the request content and add back the modified form. I don't think I'm on right lines, or at least it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mhils for assistance on this.

The problem with the script was that request.set_form_urlencoded and setting request.content both replace the content of the [HTTPRequest](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/libmproxy/protocol/http.py). You should set one or the other.

I was mistakenly thinking I should code my proxy filter to preserve any additional form parameters in the incoming request. But on reflection, HTTP POST does not mix different content-types. So discarding the form is correct.

The revised script produces a valid request:

```
def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.method == "POST":
        form = flow.request.get_form_urlencoded()
        real_post = form.get_first("phony_param")
        if real_post:
            flow.request.content = real_post
```